# Editing Python Program

Tags: python

```
Message = input("Enter a message: ")
vowels=Message.count('a')+ Message.count('i')+Message.count('e')+Message.count('u')+Message.count('o')
print ('There are ',vowels,' vowels.')
```

How would I edit the function to include the function "Vowels(text)" and still work the same?

Comment: Is this homework? The code you posted doesn't make any sense so you'll want to post the actual question as well so we can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Have you read the Python tutorial? http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Comment: `print "there are %d vowels" %sum((map(lambda x: Message.lower().count(x), 'aeiou')))`

Comment: The question was to write a program which asks the user to enter a message, and the program returns the number of vowels in the message.

Comment: I've edited it with a working program but I need to input a function called "Vowels(text)" which I have not done, and cannot do whilst making it still work

Answer (score 1):

Basically your program is OK, but you don't have the right syntax.  You need a proper function definition like

```
# fn count vowels
def vowels(text):
    NumVowels = text.count('a') + text.count('e') + ...
    return NumVowels
```

Note that Python does need the indentation.  And the rest is pretty straightforward:

```
message = input("enter a message: ")
print ('there are', vowels(message), 'vowels')
```

I like this tutorial: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-189-a-gentle-introduction-to-programming-using-python-january-iap-2011/index.htm

Comment: the function definition must be before the lines where the function is called.  Why can't you edit your program and put some lines for the function definition above where you call the function, like I showed in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2

def Vowels(text):
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    numvowels = sum(text.count(i) for i in vowels)
    return numvowels

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Message = input("Enter a message: ")
    vowels = Vowels(Message)
    print ('There are ',vowels,' vowels.')
```

It works the same, but there are a few issues:

- I'm using a `__main__` guard and you're not. You probably should be, and you might not know what it even is, so see this: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#modules-scripts
- You're using uppercase for function names. I followed along since you seemed to require it. The convention in the Python community is that function/method names should be all lower case. This convention, like many others, is driven by "PEP 8". Do a search for 'Function Names' on this page: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/
- The code would be more readable if that last print statement looked like this:

  `print("There are %s vowels" % vowels)`

  There are other ways to do it too, but this one suffices and is a common convention.
- It would be good to indicate that you're using Python 3 when you post ;-)